# Running Neural Network model on Django web app

Tags: python, django, neural-network

I'd like to include a NN classifier in a web app I am developing but I am relatively new to Django and not sure how to structure it in the best way.

Basically I would like to load the model when the server starts and as necessary pass a string to the "predict" method of the classifier and return the result. Should I include the classifier class in the views and pass forward the "predict" method as context to the page the classifier will be used on? Really I am just looking for advice and guidance and this is my first web application

Comment: This is really vague still. What exactly is the flow of events? One thing to remember is: Django is just python, so if there's a python class you need to use to render results in a page, just import that class, instantiate it and use it (in your views or in a mixin that you add to your views). Go ahead, try something, write some code, and ask a more specific question when you hit a wall.

Comment: https://medium.com/@burgalon/deploying-your-keras-model-35648f9dc5fb

Comment: If all you want is a web API, you might consider Flask, just because it's lighter weight

Comment: Unfortunately it's not just a web API but a full web application just having this as an embedded feature in the Django application. But thank you all for the replies, I literally just wanted some guidance as to how would be the best way to approach this and these answers have helped